# Select data from multiple tables with the same column names

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables in a single database;

UserAccount table;
[UserAccount table][1]

User table
[User table][2]

EducationLevels Table
[EducationLevels table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzV2c.png)

Institution table
[Institution table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8HbW.png)

Please notice that both Institution and EducationLevels table have the same coulmn names.

I am trying to query the database using;

```
SELECT 
      Users.FirstName, 
      Users.LastName, 
      UserAccounts.OtherNames,
      UserAccounts.Gender, 
      UserAccounts.DateOfBirth, 
      Institutions.Name as School, 
      EducationLevels.Name as Study
FROM 
      Users, UserAccounts,Institutions
WHERE 
      UserAccounts.HighestEducationLevelId = EducationLevels.Id 
      AND 
      UserAccounts.InstitutionId = Institutions.Id 
      AND 
      UserAccounts.UserId = Users.IdUserAccounts
      AND 
      MobileNumber ='*****';
```

I get an error:

```
     Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'EducationLevels.Name' in 'field 
    list'
```

Comment: i don't see any EducationLevels table name in your  from clause  . add table name like this  *FROM 
      Users, UserAccounts,Institutions,EducationLevels*

Comment: you haven't included `EducationLevels` in your from clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the **"FROM"** clause does not have the table name. Also, add aliases to the table names so that it'll be easier to use them across the query.

```
SELECT 
      usr.FirstName, 
      usr.LastName, 
      accounts.OtherNames,
      accounts.Gender, 
      accounts.DateOfBirth, 
      inst.Name as School, 
      eduLevel.Name as Study
FROM 
      Users usr, UserAccounts accounts, Institutions inst, EducationLevels eduLevel
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
FROM Users, UserAccounts,Institutions
```

`EducationLevels` table is not there

You forget to add `EducationLevels` in the FROM table name listing, only `Users, UserAccounts,Institutions` are there.

Comment: Thanks guys... I really should have looked well.